# var.push and to display my new temporary information in a html page

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var etat = {
    "outbox": [{
        "to": "90221F212A4200001AA",
        "date": "2016 01 12 20:15:42",
        "msg": "What are u doin ?." 
    }],
};

$("#b4").click(function() {
    etat.outbox.push({
        to: $("#@").text(),
        msg: $("#msg").text(),
        date:new Date()
    });
    var new ("#b2") = ("#b4");
});
```

I use a form and submit bar from my html where i can write new msgs and new email but i cannot display the temporary new information, i am missing a code ... how can i do that please

Comment: Please take the time to format your code properly; it was a mess previously. It makes it much easier and quicker for others to read, meaning you're likely to get faster and more accurate answers

Comment: thank you so much , i am new in here , i will do my best next time

Comment: Rory , do you have any answer to my question please ?

Comment: Not really, as it's not at all clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: can you explain precisely what do you want to do. The current code you have posted so far is just adding an object in your outbox array

Comment: I need to display information from the var.outbox database in a html page , its an email interface. to see old msgs i use this code : $("#b2").click( function (){
etat.outbox.forEach( function(msg){
  $("#id").append(
    $("<h1>").text(msg.date));

    $("#id").append(
      $("<h1>").text(etat.yp[msg.to].name));
      $("#id").append(
        $("<h1>").text(msg.msg));

Comment: YESS VIVEK you are right , now i want to display the new information on the screen

Comment: please post this code in your question in understandable form

Comment: but the thing is it displays only the old one , my teacher told me to use a render methode but dont know what that is

Comment: please guys u ought to explain to me how to use those little box that you format code

Comment: you want to show all the objects in outbox or just recently added object in your HTML page\?

Comment: all of it please , the new one and the old , if its possible , or just the new one ... just to begin

Comment: ok how to use render at least ? @VIVEK

Comment: ok see my answer. sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to bind all the outbox data in table you can use -

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var etat = {
            "outbox": [{
                "to": "90221F212A4200001AA",
                "date": "2016 01 12 20:15:42",
                "msg": "What are u doin ?."
            }],
        };

        bindTable();    

        $("#b4").click(function () {
            etat.outbox.push({
                to: $("#to").val(),
                msg: $("#msg").val(),
                date: new Date()
            });
            bindTable();
        });

        function bindTable() {
            $("#tbl tbody").empty();
            etat.outbox.forEach(function (data) {

                $("#tbl").append("<tr><td>" + data.to + "</td><td>" + data.msg + "</td><td>" + data.date + "</td></tr>");
            });

        }

    });
</script>

 <input type="text" id="to" />
<input type="text" id="msg" />
<button type="button" id="b4">Submit</button>
<table id="tbl" border="1">
    <th>To</th>
     <th>From</th>
     <th>Msg</th>
</table>
```

it will show all the data of your outbox in the table andd append new data when you add new object in your outbox

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this;

```js
var etat = {
 outbox: []
    }
$("#b4").click(function() {
    etat.outbox.push({
        to: $("#to").val(),
        msg: $("#msg").val(),
        date: new Date()
    });
    showMessages()
});
var output;
$("#new-messages").click(function() {
 showMessages()
});


function showMessages(){
 $("#to").val("");
    $("#msg").val("");
 output = "";
    etat.outbox.forEach(function(data){
     output += "TO: " + data.to + "<br> Message: " + data.msg + " <br>Date: " + data.date + "<br><br>"
    });
    $("#output").html(output)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="to">
    TO:
</label>
<input type="text" id="to">
<div>
    <label for="msg">
        Message
    </label>
        <textarea name="msg" id="msg" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
</div>
<button id="b4">
    SEND!
</button>
<div id="new-messages">
    Click to see messages
</div>

<div id="output">

</div>
```

Comment: this is great but you are not using var.push and render sir @Hakan kose thank you so much

Comment: the web site doesn't allow me to write all my code in here. now in the comments box